# add BigInteger in a loop to a List

Tags: java

I'm stuck on a probably simple thing, but I just can't figure it out.
So this is the code:

```
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    list.add(new BigInteger("i"));
}
```

I get the following Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NumberFormatException`: For input string: `"i"`

I don't understand it, i is an integer between 1-12 and it should be convertible to a BigInteger.

Comment: Please always take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-) of a class when experiencing such issues. The documentation clearly states that the input must represent a valid `BigInteger` and the text `"i"` (literally containing only the **character** `i`) obviously is no valid number. You need to first evaluate the variable, extract its number and convert this number to a `String` like `i  + ""` or `String.valueOf(i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `"i"` is not a valid representation of a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

As there is no constructor taking a single `int` parameter in the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class, you can use `String.valueOf` to return the string representation of the integer `i`:

```
list.add(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(i)));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out!

Comment: A bit cleaner would be to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)

Comment: I think the confusion comes from `"i"` not interpreting the value of `i` but instead representing the text `"i"` literally containing the **character** `i`, not the value after interpreting `i` as variable. Especially other languages such as PHP interpret variables inside strings, Java does not.

Comment: @Zabuza I guess so, in C# one could also do `$"{i}"`, which would work.  I guess this is Java functioning differently as opposed to other languages. which is completely understandable IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    list.add(BigInteger.valueOf(i)); // Fix
}
```

This way is more efficient than the selected answer because the selected one first converts the `int` to a `String` and than parses the `String` back into an `int` which is really slow.